# UIViewController遷移の標準は何か？

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

swift4 xcode10でのUIViewController同士の遷移の標準はどのようなものでしょうか。
調べてみるとその多くが、xcodeのstoryboardのGUIからsegueを接続して...という内容で、純粋にコードのみでの実装がなかなか見つからず、また、目的に応じた実装がいくつかあることがわかり、質問させていただきました。

前提条件で遷移の方法は変わってくると思います。
思いついたものとして、

1.遷移元UIVCが親となり、子での処理が終わると親に戻るパタン
2.遷移元UIVCを破棄して、遷移先がMainのUIVCとなるパタン

1,2の他の前提条件はありますでしょうか。また、それぞれの遷移の方法として、標準とされている、もしくは便利な方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
原則コードのみの実装で、実現できる方法が知りたいです。

少し変わってきてしまうかもしれませんが、segueをコードで定義し、UIVC同士の関係性を定義することは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

```
let VC = SecondViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```